How does one retry a failed build on a scripted pipeline?
Is there a way to trigger a retry on a scripted pipeline if the pipeline fails?
properties([
            parameters([
                string(defaultValue: "", description: 'optional_param1', name: "optional_param1"),
                string(defaultValue: "", description: 'optional_param2', name: "optional_param2"),
                string(defaultValue: "", description: 'optional_param3', name: "optional_param3"),
            ]),
            pipelineTriggers([cron(cronExpression)]),
        ])

I see that there are plenty of options for declarative pipeline  with options block:
options {
   retry (3)
}


and for specific blocks, but I am looking for something that would retry the cronjob if it fails to fire or if the previous build fails.

There is a retry step that does pretty much the same thing as options { retry }. Just wrap it around your entire scripted pipeline.
If your cronjob fails to fire (like missing jenkinsfile) then you are SOL, there is no retry for that. Some sort of a dead man switch monitor might alert you, if you set it up, but Jenkins on its own will not retry.
